# protractor-html-reporter screenshot is corrupted

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm using protractor to automate testing an angularjs application. I use protractor-html-reporter to generate reports.

In a hooks.js file I have placed the following code, in order to generate a screenshot whenever a test scenario fails. The image then is attached to the report.

```
this.After(function (scenario,callback) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (base64png) {
            var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64png, 'base64').toString('binary');
             scenario.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png');
             callback();
        }, function (err) {
            return callback(err);
        });
    } else{
        callback();
    }
});
```

The JSON, html and screenshot files are generated. The reports are readable and can be viewed using a browser or text editor. However, the screenshot ("png") file is always "damaged".

In the report, the image displays like reserved space (X symbol inside a black square). When trying to open the screenshot using a graphic editor, it tells that the image is damaged.

[This is the html report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1rb2.jpg)

[This is the image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdH9C.jpg)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why you are decoding?  I am using protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter which fine for me taking snap as png file...

Comment: THANKS!!   Nice, that was the problem. Thanks so the code should be:

this.After(function (scenario,callback) {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (base64png) {
              scenario.attach(new Buffer(base64png, 'base64'), 'image/png');
                 callback();
            }, function (err) {
                return callback(err);
            });
        } else{
         callback();
        }
    });